# apache + reverse proxy to another apache, 504 Gateway Time-out after 30 second

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I've a easy php script that look like this :

```
sleep(35);
echo 'ok';
```

When I try to acces this URL on server A everything is working fine, i don't get any time out (i see 'ok')

Then I've a server B where I setup a reverse proxy like this on

```
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyTimeout 300
ProxyPass /old-domain/ https://exemple.com/gestion/ timeout=1200     KeepAlive=On disablereuse=On
ProxyPassReverse /old-domain/ https://exemple.com/gestion/ timeout=1200
```

When I access to URL on server B after 30 second this error appear : 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: proxy apache log?

Comment: @lg. What do you mean exactly ? You want apache error log ? on serveur B ? Or it's possible to add specific log for ProxyPass in Apache ? Thank you

Comment: in your proxypass try "connectiontimeout  timeout  Connect timeout in seconds. The number of seconds Apache httpd waits for the creation of a connection to the backend to complete. By adding a postfix of ms, the timeout can be also set in milliseconds. "

Comment: Thank you, i've try to add connection timeout, but I still have 504 error. I've try to put all timeout to 1200 second, and i've my timeout after 30 second. If I try wget from server B to URL, I retreive my page without error HTTP 200.

Comment: I mean apache logs on server B. To discover if yuor request arrive to server B and why it goes timeout.

Comment: I have added my question in saparate thread, Thanks. https://serverfault.com/questions/948312/apache-reverse-proxy-timeout-in-60-seconds